# MathJax inline formula with standard delimiter not properly rendered with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: python, selenium, wkhtmltopdf, mathjax

Using python, selenium, beautifulsoap and wkhtmltopdf/pdfkit, I am rendering a webpages containing MathJax formulas to PDF files (actually, the pages are from a moodle site). While rendering MathJax formulas that are displayed as blocks and using standard delimiters `$$` are working flawlessly, MathJax formulas that are displayed inline using standard delimiters `\(` and `\)` are rendered with issues:

Example HTML:

```
<span>Dabei wird \(u\left ( t \right )\) mit dem ...</span>
```

Correct output on display:

[image]

Rendered PDF by wkhtmltopdf:

[image]

This issue occurs only with MathJax versions newer than 2.7.4:
The website the pdf is made from, is built on moodle 3.6 and uses MathJax 2.7.8, which is default version for moodle 3.6). If I change version of mathjax to 2.7.4 or below, the PDF is rendered correctly.

Does someone know how to solve this issue? Or at least has a clue how to track down the reason for the issue step-by-step?

EDIT: the python code for fetching page and rendering PDF file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, WebDriverException
import time
import pdfkit
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import os

server = dict({'server': 'https://example.com/login', 'user': 'admin', 'password':'abc123'})
target_url = r"https://example.com"
filename = 'export/pdf/TestPDF-0006.pdf'

wkhtmltopdf_options = {
    'page-height': 5000,
    'page-width': 210,
    'enable-local-file-access': None,
    'javascript-delay': 30000,
    'no-stop-slow-scripts': None
}

def set_driver_gecko():
    my_dpi = 2.0
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("layfilename.css.devPixelsPerPx", str(my_dpi))
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, firefox_profile=profile)
    driver.set_page_load_timefilename(60)
    driver.set_window_size(1440, 800)
    return driver

def login_and_render_pdf(server):
    driver = set_driver_gecko()
    driver.get(server['server'])
    time.sleep(3)
    # set credentials 
    user_input = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
    user_input.send_keys(server['user'])
    passwd_input = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    passwd_input.send_keys(server['password'])
    # click login
    login_btn = driver.find_element_by_class_name("login")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", login_btn)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.get(target_url)
    time.sleep(3)
    # get page
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = str(BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser"))
    # generate PDF
    pdfkit.from_string(soup,filename, options = wkhtmltopdf_options)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    login_and_render_pdf(server)
```

Comment: Tested on chrome, it is working for me

Comment: @koder613 which version of MathJax are you using, could you provide a link to the CDN? You said, you tested it on Chrome: does that mean, you used selenium with chrome driver and rendered with wkhtmltopdf or did you just browse it with Chrome?

Comment: Without selenium etc. see https://www.codeply.com/p/1r7asXtGjm

Comment: @koder613 The issue occurs when rendering a PDF, on the website everything is displayed correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, please can you post *all* the relevant code then?

Comment: I added the program code to my original question and clarified that the issue occurs on MathJax versions greater than 2.7.4